# Using $data as a condition in knockout's foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a way to use the `$data` variable as part of a condition inside of a `foreach` statement?

For example:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: ['foo', 'bar']"> 
  <p data-bind="css: { active: myObservable() === $data}"></p>
</div>
```

Knockout doesn't seem to like this syntax and throws an error. Is there a way to make the `$data` variable usable inside of nested conditions?

Comment: `throws an error` what error? And I don't see you using `$data` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once inside a `foreach` scope, you need to use `$root` to refer to your `myObservable`:

```
<p data-bind="css: { active: $root.myObservable() === $data}"></p>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qz7abj3c/1/)

Comment: *In this case*, yes. But, once I already know `myObservable` is indeed defined in root scope, I prefer to use `$root`.